# Displaying a checkbox column in a Flex DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, actionscript, itemrenderer

I am trying to create a custom Flex DataGrid which consists of two columns, one for label and the other for a checkbox.
The checkbox is contained within a class called CustomRenderer that inherits from GridItemRenderer and implements IFactory.

In each instance of CustomRenderer, I have a variable called number so that when a checkbox is clicked, it can pass back the number so that I know which row has been clicked.

The problem is that my CustomRenderer does not show when the program runs.

Please could someone help.

Here is my code.

MyProgram.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               initialize="initData()">

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.CheckBox;
            import mx.rpc.events.AbstractEvent;

            private var ArrayItems:Array = [
                {Label:'Table'},
                {Label:'Chair'},
                {Label:'Stool'},
                {Label:'Bench'},
                {Label:'Sofa'}];

            [Bindable]
            private var ArrayCollectionItems:ArrayCollection;

            private var t:CustomRenderer;

            public function initData():void
            {
                ArrayCollectionItems=new ArrayCollection(ArrayItems);

                t = new CustomRenderer();
                t.cb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, HandleClick);
                MainGrid.columns[1].itemRenderer = t.newInstance();     
            }

            public function HandleClick(event:Event):void
            {
                var c:CustomRenderer = (event.currentTarget) as CustomRenderer
                var RowClicked:int = c.number;
            }       

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="State1"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Panel x="99" y="14" width="379" height="268" skinClass="spark.skins.spark.PanelSkin">
        <s:DataGrid id="MainGrid" x="19" y="17" width="340" height="199"
                    dataProvider="{ArrayCollectionItems}" requestedRowCount="4" requireSelection="false"
                    resizableColumns="false" selectionMode="singleRow" showDataTips="false">
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn minWidth="200" dataField="Label" headerText="Label"></s:GridColumn>
                    <s:GridColumn minWidth="30" dataField="" headerText="">                 
                    </s:GridColumn>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
            <s:typicalItem>
                <fx:Object dataField1="Sample Data" dataField2="Sample Data" dataField3="Sample Data"></fx:Object>
            </s:typicalItem>
        </s:DataGrid>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

CustomRenderer.as

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.CheckBox;
import mx.core.IFactory;

import spark.components.gridClasses.GridItemRenderer;

public class CustomRenderer extends GridItemRenderer implements IFactory
{   
    private static var count:int = 0;
    public var number:int;
    public var cb:CheckBox;

    public function CustomRenderer()
    {       
        cb = new CheckBox();
        number = count++;
        cb.x = 22;
        cb.y = 4;           
        addElement(cb);
    }

    public function newInstance():*
    {
        return new CustomRenderer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because you pass an instance of the itemrenderer to the column (new CustomRenderer()) instead of a class (CustomRenderer). The common approach is to pass the itemrenderer class to your column and then handle the clicks / selection inside of it:

```
<s:GridColumn minWidth="30" headerText="" itemRenderer="com.yourpackage.CustomRenderer">
```

Just start typing "Customrenderer" when you assign it and you should be able to autocomplete so it writes out your full package path.

Then you catch the checkbox select events inside of the renderer and could set some custom data property (for example, data.selected). If you really need to do something outside of your Grid after the selection you might need to fire a custom event from your renderer on selection and listen for it on your datagrid.

Comment: I have modified my code so that I can now send the row and column of the checkbox that was selected back to the main class using a custom event.

Comment: I need to add another column which will display a button and when clicked will remove the row that the button sits in, so I am now scrapping the row and column numbering. What I want to do is bind the checkbox value to an element in an ArrayCollection variable. But how do bind a checkbox value in one class to an arraycollection declared in another class?

Comment: You need to override the set data(), createChildren() and commitProperties() methods in your itemrenderer. Move the creation of the checkbox into the createChildren() method - this is the standard Flex life cycle practice. set data() is the place where the object is passed to your itemrenderer. Here you could look up the property value of your object (for example, "selected") and store the property in your local variables. Then in commitProperties() you set the state of your checkbox depending on the "selected" value.